# Applying translation to custom WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to apply a translation to my cusom plugin. I've alredy created **brau-ru_RU.mo** and **brau-ru_RU.po** files. My translation domain is 'brau'.

What I've tried is to put files in **wp-content/languages/plugins/** and execute this code in my plugin.

```
$domain = 'brau';
$mo_file = WP_LANG_DIR.'/plugins/'.$domain.'-'.get_locale(). '.mo';

var_dump(load_textdomain( $domain, $mo_file )); 
var_dump(load_plugin_textdomain( $domain ));
var_dump(__('This is the test', 'brau'));
```

Result is:

```
bool(true) bool(true) string(16) "This is the test"
```

I also got this code in my config

```
define ('WPLANG', 'ru_RU');
```

The text shoud be translated from English to Russian, but it's not. What am I missing?

This is a link to test version of the plugin: https://github.com/Brezgalov/brezgalovauth

Comment: is your get_locale() returning ru_RU?

Comment: and is the path correct, if you var_dump($mo_file);

Comment: Yes, get_locale and $mo_file is ok, just checked it twice

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add language files to your plugin then you can create a folder called languages inside your plugin folder  and in the plugin main file you can define like this

```
// Localiztion with language files
function custom_langs_i18n() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'textdomain', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_langs_i18n' );
```

Please remember to use textdomain where you are using string.

Comment: I've tried to do so, didn't succeed also. load_plugin_textdomain returns true and the text is still Eng. Tried it again with no changes

Comment: Can you share your plugin so that we can check the issue?

Comment: did you compile your mo file properly?

Comment: I've added a link to the repo to question post. 
I compile mo with poedit, does mo files can be wrong?